# Specify Heroku addon version in app.json

Tags: postgresql, heroku, configuration

When using `heroku addons:create`, one may specify a version, e.g. as shown in [this](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/1/7/postgres-95-now-available-on-heroku) Heroku blog post introducing Postgres 9.5:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql --version=9.5
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I asked support and they said "we don't have a way to configure addon flags for review apps yet"

Comment: @nicholaides this appears to have been implemented now, see accepted answer.

Comment: I actually have the inverse question: I'm trying to do the short-and-sweet `"addons": ["heroku-postgresql"]` or even `"addons": [{"plan": "heroku-postgresql"}]` without pinning any specific version, and it's not working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
  "addons": [
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
      "options": {
        "version": "9.5"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#example-app-json

Comment: Yey! Looks like it was added sometime between now and [back in May](https://web.archive.org/web/20160508102505/https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons) :)